# Angularjs sorting by time 24hrs

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I want to implement sorting for my table fields. I have one column which shows time. Here is the example I tried

```
  <tr><td ng-click="predicate = 'appointmentTime'; reverse=!reverse">AdmitTime</td></tr>
    <tr ng-cloak ng-repeat='listItem in apptList | filterencounters:searchModel | orderBy:predicate:reverse' ng-class='rowClass(listItem)'>
    <td>{{listItem.appointmentTime}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Above code is working, but it is sorting based in AM & PM

[image]

I would like to sort by 24hrs.

Comment: Share your filter code to check

Comment: you cant sort dates like that angular treat them as normal string not as a date. you can pass the date in 24h system from the backend and format it to desired format in the frontend and show

Comment: @mohamedrias , I have included filter code in my question

Comment: I've created a custom sort function which you can use :)

Comment: @K.Toress, I think you are right. It is treating them as a string thats why it is sorting based on AM & PM.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code with custom filter:

I've used `moment.js` for the custom sorting here.

```js
   angular.module("app", [])
.controller("Cont", function($scope){
  $scope.apptList  = [{
time : "01:00 PM"
  },
  {
time : "02:05 PM"
  },
  {
time : "10:42 AM"
  },
  {
time : "10:44 AM"
  },
  {
time : "10:45 AM"
  }];
})
.filter('customOrderBy', function () {
   return function (arr, parameter) {
 return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
   return moment(b.time, "hh:mm A").diff(moment(a.time, "hh:mm A")) > 0 ? -1 : 1;
 });
};
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Cont">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="app in apptList | customOrderBy">{{app.time}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have to do this in angular with out using external js like moment.js. Anyway thanks for your reply

Comment: @NoOne Great, Hope you got the point now. You can just change the sort function and do the comparison yourself to get desired results

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to store `Date` objects, sort them then convert them to your format with a filter: `{{ listItem.appointedTime | date : 'HH:mm a' }}`.